# Shapes adjusted closer in Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010, shapes

I searched for my query but could not find any better answer. I need to adjust my shapes closer so that I can fix most of my shapes in one page. Currently there is larger space between the shapes if I use auto option. I want them to be closer and connecters still attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. You need to o go to Menu>>Home>>Position>> select spacing option and reduce the Distance between the each shape.